# filter All strings that have sub-string starting with "rajesh" till "Talasu" and replace with new word

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hi I want to write a regular expression in **Javascript** for below use case.

I have a input as array of strings like:

1. "Hi i am **rajesh Kumar Talasu**, working on xyz company."
2. "Hi i am **rajesh token1 Talasu**, working on xyz company."
3. "Hi i am **rajesh token2 Talasu**, working on xyz company."

I want to filter All strings that have sub-string starting with "rajesh" till "Talasu" and replace with new word

So regular expression should give me result as below:

1. "Hi i am **Raj Kumar**, working on xyz company."
2. "Hi i am **Raj Kumar**, working on xyz company."
3. "Hi i am **Raj Kumar**, working on xyz company."

Answer (score 1):

```
/rajesh.*?Talasu/

"Hi i am rajesh Kumar Talasu, working on xyz company.".replace(/rajesh.*?Talasu/, "Raj Kumar");
//"Hi i am Raj Kumar, working on xyz company."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  yourstring.replace(/rajesh.*Talasu/, "what ever")
```

**Edit**

This is greedy version, it will match the first **rajesh** to the last **Talasu**, you can use the lazy version for better performance and exactness as

```
  yourstring.replace(/rajesh.+?Talasu/,"whatever")
```

Thank for your comment Derek
Hope this help

Comment: Yes, it is greedy, but you know, his requirement not specified it :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\brajesh\b.+?\bTalasu\b/, "Raj Kumar");
```